# Access WMTS from a GeoTIFF Layer in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, mapproxy

I created a layer in GeoServer from a GeoTIFF-source.
I can access this layer via WMS through the following URLs:

mapproxy:

http://10.77.70.19:8080/geoserver/germany/wms?SERVICE=WMS&

I have enabled GeoWebCache for that layer.

I want to create a WMTS layer through mapproxy by combining this layer with another WMTS layer. Combining WMS and WMTS to create WMTS seems to not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Request the GeoServer layer as a [WMTS tile set via GeoWebCache](https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/services/wmts.html) (which is built into your GeoServer install) - MapProxy should be able to combine two WMTS layers.
2. Use GeoServer to [cascade the external WMTS](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/cascaded/wmts.html) so that it appears as "just" another WMS/WMTS layer. Your client can then request both the layers together, possibly using a [Layer Group](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/webadmin/layergroups.html) to combine them into one.